# Выполнение синхронного запроса Axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, axios

Как выполнить синхронный запрос через `axios`?

```
              $(event.target.files).each(function( index,value,form ) { //Идем по массиву загруженных картинок
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', value);  //Присваиваем переменной загруженную фотку
                axios.post('/upload/article/images',formData,config) //Загружаем фотку на сервак и присылаем обратно название
                    .then((response) => {
                        if (response.data.error === 0) {
                            let el = that.form.find((f, idx) => f.galleryIndex == '' && idx >= tnum);
                            if (el){
                                el.galleryIndex = value.name
                            }
                            else{
                                that.form.push({
                                    title: '',
                                    description: '',
                                    galleryIndex: value.name
                                });
                            }
                            toast.fire({
                                type: 'success',
                                title: response.data.message
                            });
                        }else{
                            toast.fire({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: response.data.message
                            });
                        }

                        that.loading = false;

                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            });
```

Comment: это операция сама по себе асинхронная, ее нельзя выполнить синхронно, но можно использовать `await` , что бы синтаксис выглядел, как синхронный

Comment: а как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться `async/await` конструкциями, которые позволяют писать "синхронный код" для асинхронных задач

```
async function loadData() {
  const response = await fetch('url');
  // далее делаем что-нибудь с response
  сonst data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

// где-то в коде
await loadData(); // можно и без await, если дожидаться рузультата не обязательно
```

**P.S.**
Вообще, до `fetch` для запросов использовали `XMLHttpRequest`, который позволял делать именно синхронные запросы

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'url', false); // параметр false означает синхронность
```

**Подребнее**
[async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) 
[xmlhttprequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: и пофакту все равно асинхронно.)))